# Python fillna not fill completely

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on the dataset with a column with missing data. I intended to fill it with the proportion of the data and I think I got that part covered. However, after running fillna, value counts suggest that I still have missing value in the new data frame. (output 95 still shows nan values)

Any thoughts on what is going on?

```
valuecounts = df['parentocclist'].value_counts(dropna=False)
valuecountsinsample = df['parentocclist'].value_counts(normalize=True)
df['parentocclist2']=df['parentocclist'].fillna(pd.Series(np.random.choice([0.0,1.0,2.0],p=[0.656,0.268,0.076],size=len(df)))) # assign the value with probabiliy of insample sizes
valuecountsnew = df['parentocclist2'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

```
valuecounts
Out[93]: 
0.0    3559
NaN    2162
1.0    1456
2.0     411
Name: parentocclist, dtype: int64
valuecountsinsample
Out[94]: 
0.0    0.655916
1.0    0.268338
2.0    0.075746
Name: parentocclist, dtype: float64
valuecountsnew
Out[95]: 
0.0    4372
1.0    1838
NaN     854
2.0     524
Name: parentocclist2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: did you try using different methods to fill the series?

Comment: @lhdamiani I shouldn't use bfill and ffill in this case as I already have a series generated right?

Comment: hard to tell without a reproducible example but probably index misalignment in `fillna` with the input `Series`; likely need to pass `index=df.index` in the `Series` constructor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `fillna` method, if you specify an dict/Series/DataFrame object, then you need to clarify wich indexes should be filled, for example:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3], 100000, replace=True),
              columns=['sample_column'])
df.sample_column.value_counts(dropna=False)

# 2.0    20142
# 3.0    20140
# 0.0    19979
# 1.0    19978
# NaN    19761
```

Now, generate the series of values to replace nans, and set the index the locations of the nan values on your `df`:

```
nan_index = df.index.values[df.sample_column.isnull()]
serie_na = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                                      p=[0.656, 0.268, 0.076],
                                      size=len(nan_index)),
                     index=nan_index)
df.sample_column.fillna(serie_na).value_counts(dropna=False)

# 0.0    32974
# 1.0    25248
# 2.0    21638
# 3.0    20140
```